# Cursor size does not match text size when user is typing in input

Tags: html, css, browser

I've set a font-size on all of my input elements and also a line-height of 1.25. For some reason, on mobile web (currently trying with Android Chrome) the blinking cursor is much shorter than the text itself, and results in the text getting cut in the middle when the user is actively entering input. The actual text itself ends up being fine after the user exits the input (doesn't get cut off). How can I make sure that the cursor matches the real size of the text? I attached a picture for reference.

On desktop web browsers (Windows, Mac + Chrome, Safari, Firefox) it's totally fine and I don't experience this issue, although apparently on Firefox Linux the same issue pops up.

Code so far:

```css
.input-class {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  line-height: 1.25 !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-class::placeholder {
  overflow: visible;
}

.input-class:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input-class">
```

Any comments are appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Save people the hassle of writing out and/or guessing what your html and css are, if they want to experiment with the problem.

Comment: @wazz added the CSS, the HTML would just be a single <input type="text"> tag

Comment: Added a snippet. I don't have a device to test on. Just guessing I would start by removing the padding on the input element (seems high?) and/or play with the line-height some more to see if they do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue after doing Remote Debugging with Chrome - highly recommend this in the future if you're also facing some similar issues on mobile. The custom font that I was using was not playing nicely with inputs and textareas on Chrome. I switched to a more common font and the issue went away.